# How to execute huge queries on big query cloud shell?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Here is my code

```sql
with table1 as (
    select * from emp
),
table2 as (
    select * from dept
),
table3 as (
    select * from attendance
)

select table1.*,table2.*,table3.*;
```

When I run this query It doesn't show any output but gives the following message

`Waiting on bqjob_r1556eb3ce0e18e00_0000016a1558a3b2_1 ... (10s) Current status: DONE`

but when I try to run this :

```sql
select table1.name;
```

It gives the following output :

```
+----------------+
|      Name      |
+----------------+
| Ahmad Abdullah |
+----------------+
```

When the result set contains 5-6 columns then it gives output but when it is more than 5-6 columns then it is not showing any output

I want to know how can we execute huge queries with more than 10 columns in big query cloud shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know how can we execute huge queries with more than 10 columns in big query cloud shell

This is an example of how to run a query in BigQuery cloud shell on multiple columns, check the job status and fetch the results from the destination table 
(I'm using, in this case, a public dataset so you can test and play with this)

- Running a query use: `bq query`

```sh
bq query --nouse_legacy_sql 'select * from `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare` limit 10'
```

> Waiting on bqjob_r35189e6fbf98cf71_0000016a16517f64_1 ... (0s) Current status: DONE

```
+-----------+------------+---------+-------------+
|   word    | word_count | corpus  | corpus_date |
+-----------+------------+---------+-------------+
| LVII      |          1 | sonnets |           0 |
| augurs    |          1 | sonnets |           0 |
| dimm'd    |          1 | sonnets |           0 |
| plagues   |          1 | sonnets |           0 |
| treason   |          1 | sonnets |           0 |
| surmise   |          1 | sonnets |           0 |
| heed      |          1 | sonnets |           0 |
| Unthrifty |          1 | sonnets |           0 |
| quality   |          1 | sonnets |           0 |
| wherever  |          1 | sonnets |           0 |
+-----------+------------+---------+-------------+
```

- Monitoring job status use: `bq show`:

```sh
bq --location=US show -j 'bqjob_r35189e6fbf98cf71_0000016a16517f64_1'
```

- Output:

```
Job projectId:bqjob_r35189e6fbf98cf71_0000016a16517f64_1
  Job Type    State      Start Time      Duration         User Email         Bytes Processed   Bytes Billed   Billing Tier   Labels
 ---------- --------- ----------------- ---------- ------------------------ ----------------- -------------- -------------- --------
  query      SUCCESS   13 Apr 13:50:01   0:00:00    tamir.klein1@gmail.com   6432064           10485760
```

- To get Jobs Details use: `--format=prettyjson`

```sh
bq --location=US --format=prettyjson show -j 'bqjob_r35189e6fbf98cf71_0000016a16517f64_1'

    "destinationTable": {
            "datasetId": "_678da79776e587d77e4352f89f5345e7f20849ef",
            "projectId": "mydata",
            "tableId": "anon0dd6d6c2fda3d77bec552bbc189e4ba08a136b20"
          },
```

- To get Result for a long query use: `bq query` with the destination table information taken from the previous point

```
bq query --nouse_legacy_sql 'select * from `projectId._678da79776e587d77e4352f89f5345e7f20849ef.anon0dd6d6c2fda3d77bec552bbc189e4ba08a136b20` limit 10'
```

- Output:

```
Waiting on bqjob_r44dc9a8fdbdf61f0_0000016a1662e2ac_1 ... (0s) Current status: DONE   

+-----------+------------+---------+-------------+
|   word    | word_count | corpus  | corpus_date |
+-----------+------------+---------+-------------+
| LVII      |          1 | sonnets |           0 |
| augurs    |          1 | sonnets |           0 |
| dimm'd    |          1 | sonnets |           0 |
| plagues   |          1 | sonnets |           0 |
| treason   |          1 | sonnets |           0 |
| surmise   |          1 | sonnets |           0 |
| heed      |          1 | sonnets |           0 |
| Unthrifty |          1 | sonnets |           0 |
| quality   |          1 | sonnets |           0 |
| wherever  |          1 | sonnets |           0 |
+-----------+------------+---------+-------------+
```

Comment: @Muhammad any feedback on my answer, If it was helpful appreciate if you can accept it, see how in this link https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235

Comment: Thank you :) Please accept the answer, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#523